# Azure B2C Custom Reset Password Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a some custom policies in B2C that are working and I'm not trying to get the Reset Password to work. One of the issues I have is that I call a Restful API to check if the email address provided is a local user or if we are signing them in from a Microsoft AAD. This works fine, so the user is signed in via a Microsoft Organisation Identity if they are an SSO user, if not they are signed in locally via the B2C.

My issue is that I'm trying to do something similar with reset password. I use the following Technical Profile to get the email address

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Signin-Email">
    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin To Tax Systems</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Once the email address is obtained, we call a rest api to check the email address. This check tells us if the user is a federated user, or a local user. If they are a federated user I want to error as they can't reset their password via B2C.

If they are a local user then we want to do the reset password. This is done via the following Technical Profile. The problem is that they have to enter their email address again, I want the email address to be pre-populated with the email address obtained previously.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
  <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />

  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Any idea how I can do this? I can't seem to find much detail about `api.localaccountpasswordreset` in regards to the metadata etc.

Comment: Taking information from @alfredo-r-msft-identity, I have taken this a step further and managed to get the email address prepopulated. However, it does not then verify the email address

Answer (score 1):

Since you obtained the email in the claim `signInName` at step 1, in step 2, you can pre-populate it as follows:

```xml
  <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
  </InputClaims>
```

For the Email Verification buttons to appear, you must have the `email` claim as readOnly. Otherwise, AAD B2C will pre-populate the field assuming its already validated, and only show the Verify button if the email address is changed.

So a true solution would be:

```xml
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Sample: Read only email address to present to the user-->
      <ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
  <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="readonlyEmail"/>
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

You'd need to modify `AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress` such that its input claim is

```xml
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
</InputClaims>
```

I would copy the whole technical profile and give it a new Id with above modification.

And any further references to `email` in the joruney should be replaced with `readOnlyEmail` in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go, I assume that I would be able to create a copy of the AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress and change it to say AAD-UserReadUsingReadOnlyEmailAddress and change the input claim in that to be the readonlyEmail claim?

Comment: Thanks, I have done these changes and it now asks to validate the email address. The problem now is that once I click on the validate button nothing happens. Looking at the network traffic in Chrome, it is getting a 500 at this point, and I can't see any extra information in Application Insights to help. I'm going to try resetting my policies, and try again.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this a few times now, and keep getting the 500 error. Made the changes as you have detailed, it now shows the "Send verification code" button, however on pressing the button you get "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: If you share a correlation id from the page source, I might be able to find out what the issue is.

Comment: If you could that would be great, I’ve shut down for the day but grabbed one from AppInsights form earlier, it’s 7a9a70b9-47db-456a-a692-1e68e9be3e9b I think. I'm sure it's something silly I've probably not done

Comment: I have just grabbed another correlation id as was not sure if the other one was correct. The id is 38ff1867-2472-44a6-af7a-7cc4472f8c88 and the DC is DB3 if that helps. Not sure if it will be causing the issue but we are also using a CustomUi. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these:

```xml
<Metadata>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">True</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:email}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"></InputClaim>
</InputClaims>
```

So you can set the email calling the policy authorize URL appending an email query param (&email=someemail@somedomain.com)

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. I've updated the question with more details about the flow I think.

Comment: I've changed the InputClaim to be this


`<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{Claim:signInName}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" ></InputClaim>  `


Problem is that now it does not ask to verify the email. The email address is populated however.

Comment: @Tanzy I'm reaching within the product team and will come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working?  I had a similar setup for one of my customers and fixed this issue by adding 2 validation profiles (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile) and changed the input claim:

1. Call the REST API as a Validation Technical Profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) in your SelfAsserted-Signin-Email Technical Profile to check the Email address, display an error on the screen if the email address is not federated;
2. Call a ClaimsTransformation Validation Technical Profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) that references a ClaimsTransformation to copy signInName to email (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/general-transformations#copyclaim);
3. Change the Input Claim in your LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress Technical Profile to email.

This provides a clean UI - an error is displayed on the first form if the user is federated and the second screen pre-populates the email field using the default claim.

Comment: Not got it working yet. The issue I have is when I set the email address to be read-only. It's then that the 500 error occurs when validating the email address

Comment: Hey Tanzy, the above is based on the original TPs in the question - there should be no need to set it as read-only.  If you do need to make the email address read-only, one option may be to do the email validation as part of the first step, then copy to a new Claim with UserType of Paragraph?  That way you can display it on the second screen without allowing the user to make changes?

Comment: @ABunning Can you provide a sample for this?