# Pre-create user in B2C and send "Reset Password flow"-email pre-populated

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Graph Api to pre-create users in B2C before sending an email with a "Reset Password"-userflow URL as:

`https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ResetPassword&client_id=xxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login&code_challenge=xxx&login_hint=me@example.com`

Is there a way to pre-populate the email address field, so the user dosn't need to write it manually? I've tried appending `login_hint` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Code for creating user:

```
        `var user = new User
        {
            DisplayName = displayName,
            AccountEnabled = true,
            UserType = "Member",
            Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>()
            {
                new ObjectIdentity
                {
                    SignInType = "emailAddress",
                    Issuer = "xxx",
                    IssuerAssignedId = email
                },
            },
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                Password = password,
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
            },
            PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
            AdditionalData = customAttributes
        };

        await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(user);`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`login_hint` is used for sign-in, doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-user-flow#prepopulate-the-sign-in-name). It doesn't work in the password reset policy, and you could feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/43457076-prepopulate-password-reset-email-address).

There is no direct way to pre-populate the email address in this flow. You could use [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#custom-policy-starter-pack) to define technical profiles and user journeys. Try to see this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64016813/13308381).

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try using a custom policy